# Audio Unknown Identifier in Unity3D?

Tags: javascript, audio, unity-game-engine

I'm making a audio clip to play whenever you get "scared" in the game I am creating. I am using

```
if (SanityEffect.currentSanity >= 20)
{
      mBlur.enabled = true;
      mBlur.blurAmount = 0.2f;
      GetComponent.<AudioSource>().clip = BreathingCalm;
}
```

to call the effects and the sound. I repeat this for a few more lines, replacing 20 with 40, 60 and so forth. The sound changes every time the value changes. I am getting an 'Unknown Identifier' error, with BreathingCalm (my sound file) as the error. I set variables up top using

```
var BreathingCalm : AudioClip;
```

for every sound file I had. Anyone tell me why it is giving me this error? Thanks guys!

Comment: Is it in UnityScript ? I'm not used to that but shouldn't it be GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip instead of GetComponent.<AudioSource>().clip ?

Comment: With Unity updating, it converts Javascript into Unityscript, so yes the one you are looking at is Unityscript. Also, GetComponent.<AudioSource>().clip is properly formatted.

Comment: Seems like your audio clip is declared somewhere the method cannot access. Is it a global variable to the class? Unknown identifier is used when the name of the reference you use does not exist. So either you have a typo on the naming or the AudioClip is declared in a scope, this snippet you gave cannot see.

Comment: write the  error completely

Comment: if you have nothing more than **var BreathingCalm : AudioClip;** than the BreathingCalm object will be null. You need to locate the audio clip in your assets folder and assign it to BreathingCalm object.